# Square Up Pending Refund Sample

Tags: c#, webhooks, square-connect

I have implemented Square Up to create payments and refunds through the API. Both implementations look good but the refunds come as "Pending".

I'm trying to implement a webhook to update the payment on my end but I can't find a good example on how the workflow should work.

Also, is there a way to query for a particular refund by ID every X minutes to find the refund status instead of implementing the hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The webhooks API only posts refunds that are completed, not pending. You can poll for the state of a refund using the [retrieve transactions endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction). This response of this endpoint includes all refunds for the given transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Please check it. I suggest streamdata instead of webhook.

```
//Create refunds
var client = new RestClient("https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/{{location_id}}/transactions/{{transaction_id}}/refund");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("postman-token", "");
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer {{access_token}}");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n  \"idempotency_key\": \"YOUR_IDEMPOTENCY_KEY\",\n  \"tender_id\": \"TENDER_ID\",\n  \"reason\": \"a reason\",\n  \"amount_money\": {\n    \"amount\": 100,\n    \"currency\": \"USD\"\n  }\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

//List refunds
    var client = new RestClient("https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/{{location_id}}/refunds");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("postman-token", "");
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer {{access_token}}");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```